# Codekit Bower Component - wordpress

Tags: bower, codekit

Designing a theme for wordpress and installed it Bower Components in Codekit. 
Codekit documentation says not to move the files out of bower folder for updating purposes, but if I put my theme folder in the bower installation of wordpress won't it get deleted when I update?
What's the best way to work on my theme that doesn't involve moving wordpress folder?